# How to arrange data in dataframes according to headers python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I am using python 3.9 on Spyder, I receive data frames from a source where I can not control how the data is received. However, I know that the data is grouped under a certain header. When trying to group the data using pandas it is failing. Below is an example of the received dataframes and the output needed.

[image]

and below is how I want it to be arranged.

[image]

Any ideas on how I can achieve this? Note that I have a very large amount of data so I am searching for a method with reduced memory usage.

Edit: I had a typo in name and age, I also added that the headers are different than name and age such as column1 and column2.

Comment: To be clear: if the name and age are both mis-labelled as the other, then swap the values; otherwise don't change the row?

Comment: RegEx perhaps? Think that would be the easiest as you have a set format of the incoming data, just look for 0-9 on the right of the =

Comment: If you don't actually receive a dataframe and instead receive a file that contains "Name: Value" and "Age:Value", then [read JSON](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) might point you in the right direction.

Comment: yes there is a typo i also edited my question for headers and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your main DataFrame is the traditional variable `df`:

```
# Create a copy of the dataframe
df2 = df.copy()

# Look in the Age field where the right-side is non-numeric;
# Set that value to name
df.loc[df2["Age"].str.match(r"^\w+=\D+$"), "Name"] = df2.loc[df2["Age"].str.match(r"^\w+=\D+$"), "Age"]

# Do the opposite for the other field.
df.loc[df2["Name"].str.match(r"^\w+=\d+$"), "Age"] = df2.loc[df2["Name"].str.match(r"^\w+=\d+$"), "Name"]
```

Output of `df`:

```
          Name     Age
0     Age=John  Age=25
1     Name=Roy  Age=36
2   Name=Smith  Age=19
3  Name=Donald  Age=12
4   Name=jason  Age=57
5     Name=joe   Age=1
```

Comment: in the case where the headers are different than the content as the edit i just added what will be the workaround to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but I would just replace Name and Age with the relevant header names. If you need something to automatically sense which columns should be Name and Age, then that might be a little more work, than flipping column values :-)

Answer (score 1):

If every value begins with `Name=...` or `Age=...`, maybe simple `.transform()` will help:

```
df.loc[:, ["Name", "Age"]] = df.loc[:, ["Age", "Name"]].transform(
    sorted, axis=1
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          Name     Age
0    Name=John  Age=25
1     Name=Roy  Age=36
2   Name=Smith  Age=19
3  Name=Donald  Age=12
4   Name=Jason  Age=57
5     Name=Joe   Age=1
```

---

P.S.: I'm assuming first row should be `Name=John`, not `Age=John` (but the code should be the same).

Comment: Interesting.  You're sorting alphabetically and flip-flopping the columns while doing so?  How did you get `Name=John` to appear at the first `Name` spot?

Comment: @MarkMoretto It was `Age=John`, but I'm assuming it's a typo (every other row has Name and Age)

Comment: For sure.  I should have added a *wink* next to my comment to indicate sarcasm, lol.  Nice solution, I'm going to have to keep `.transform()` in mind for future problems.

Comment: yes, there is a typo. I also edited that my headers are different than Name and Age but known as the example in the edit.